# Is it necessary to index a has_one association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model `User`. I also have a `has_one` model `ProposedUser`

If it was a `has_many` I would have generated this migration

```
class CreateProposedUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :proposed_users do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But is indexing the user column necessary in a `has_one`?  `t.references :user, foreign_key: true`

Comment: What you mean index here?

Comment: @DipakG. Indexing the database.. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting result from child table you need to add parent id in child table, So `t.references :user, foreign_key: true` is mandatory.

But indexing not mandatory in this case. Because indexing should apply on column that are required very frequently.

Comment: So its better to have it on frequently accessed `has_one` associations aswell.. Right??

Comment: Yes, It index won't do anything wrong. It always helpful.